# Nicely print Calculator input along with the result

Tags: c#

How can I output the number, the operator, and the result at once. After the user input

```
double answer;

WriteLine("Enter your first number");
double num1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

string sign;
WriteLine("Enter any of the following operators (+,-,*,/ )");
sign = Console.ReadLine();

WriteLine("Enter your second number");
double num2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

switch (sign)
{
    case "+":
        answer = num1 + num2;
        WriteLine(answer);
        break;
    case "-":
        answer = num1 - num2;
        WriteLine(answer);
        break;
}
```

Ideally output would look like `12 + 34 = 46`, but any variations (including RPN - `12 34 + 46` would do).

Since this is homework for one of the first lessons, please don't push the envelope with suggested answers - while some input validation would be nice avoid lambda expressions and generics as we have not officially studied those.

Comment: What’s the “problem”? Just create a pass the output expected string to WriteLine? (num1, num2, and sign are all in scope). It may be useful to [interpolated strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/exploration/interpolated-strings-local).

Answer (score 3):

Here you go, for fun, here's how I would do this:

```
var calculations = new Dictionary<string, Func<double, double, double>>()
{
    { "+", (x, y) => x + y },
    { "-", (x, y) => x - y },
    { "*", (x, y) => x * y },
    { "/", (x, y) => x / y },
};

double EnterNumber(string message)
{
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
        if (double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out double value))
        {
            return value;
        }
    }
}

string EnterOperator(string message)
{
    string sign = null;
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
        if ("+-*/".Contains(sign = Console.ReadLine()))
        {
            return sign;
        }
    }
}
double num1 = EnterNumber("Enter your first number");
string sign = EnterOperator("Enter any of the following operators (+,-,*,/ )");
double num2 = EnterNumber("Enter your second number");

Console.WriteLine($"{num1} {sign} {num2} = {calculations[sign](num1, num2)}");
```

---

Here's a slightly more refactored version to eliminate as much repetition as possible.

```
var calculations = new Dictionary<string, Func<double, double, double>>()
{
    { "+", (x, y) => x + y },
    { "-", (x, y) => x - y },
    { "*", (x, y) => x * y },
    { "/", (x, y) => x / y },
};

T EnterValue<T>(string message, Func<string, (bool success, T value)> tryParse)
{
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
        var output = tryParse(Console.ReadLine());
        if (output.success)
        {
            return output.value;
        }
    }
}

double EnterNumber(string message) => EnterValue<double>(message, x =>
    double.TryParse(x, out double value) ? (true, value) : (false, default));
    
string EnterOperator(string message) => EnterValue<string>(message, x =>
    ("+-*/".Contains(x), x));

double num1 = EnterNumber("Enter your first number");
string sign = EnterOperator("Enter any of the following operators (+,-,*,/ )");
double num2 = EnterNumber("Enter your second number");

Console.WriteLine($"{num1} {sign} {num2} = {calculations[sign](num1, num2)}");
```

Comment: This answer is probably how an analytical professional senior programmer would do it. However, the OP is obviously having issues just printing a number to screen. I doubt he will have any clue how this code works. However, this code will work.

Comment: @Icemanind - Hence why I said it was for a bit of fun. I didn't think that this was a direct answer to the OP, but maybe more suitable for the wider audience here.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - Fair enough. I agree.

Comment: This answer is how I might write such an assignment, for fun. Not sure how much it helps the OP, although it should open up some idea possibilities (and further questions), especially as someone digs in deeper. Perhaps an `EnterOperator` method for parity? ;-)

Comment: @user2864740 - That was my intent - a bit of food for thought. I did consider the `EnterOperator` method, but I was trying to avoid creating unnecessary code. But I guess it shows how to modularize.

Answer (score 1):

Here it goes:-

```
 switch (sign) {
        case "+":

            answer = num1 + num2;
            WriteLine(num1+" "+num2+" + "+answer);
          
       break; 


            case "-":
            answer = num1 - num2;
            WriteLine(num1+" "+num2+" - "+answer);
            break;
    }
```

Comment: That's not right.  You have the operator in the wrong place, and you can't add numbers and strings.

Comment: @TimRoberts despite being very low quality answer and having very *limited* explanation (also I'm old and maybe "here it goes" is enough for modern students so to understand any topic) the answer actually shows completely valid code... and RPN is no worse than infix notation.

Comment: Ensure to explain the code, especially for such questions. Inline comments are suitable means to clarify, including expected output clarification.

Comment: Umm, I thought it was pretty self-explanatory but now I think I should have added the explanation as well. Thanks for the suggestion. @user2864740

Comment: Well, to someone who’s been coding for a bit ;-) I would, in my own particular writing style, probably add a note similar to `// output expression in prefix form followed by result (adapt as needed), eg. “3 1 - 2”`

Comment: @TimRoberts Huh? C# “adds” numbers and strings just fine. Any binary `+` operator with a string expression on either side will result in the other being implicitly converted to a string if it is not already a string.